# Laravel redirect to naimed route with parameters not working as intented, may I be doing something wrong?

Tags: php, laravel, web-applications, router

In a controller I'm calling the redirect helper to change the page with a named route, and i need to pass a parameter to it.

Base on the laravel documentation I did this:

`return redirect()->route('named.route', ['id_element' => 1]);`

Which should return `page/{id_element}` according to the documentation

But is actually doing `page?id_element=1`

Since I'm using `page/{id_element}` in the router it returns an error saying that there is no route to support it.

May I be doing something wrong? What is it?

I'm using Laravel 6.x

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the following command in your terminal:

```
php artisan route:list
```

This will provide you with a list of your registered routes, their names and the parameter it expects to receive.

For example, if you see this:

```
/page/{page}
```

Your method would need to be:

```
return redirect()->route('named.route', ['page' => 1]);
```

Comment: Nope, I still get the error, and I verify that everything is named correctly

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a full code example, and the output from `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Sadly I can't do that because is a private application, I hope you can understand